# Creating a filter for time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I currently have a code that plots multiple routes on top of a world map within MATLAB. However, I want to be able to tell the code the start and end date-time for the data that I want. I'm not exactly sure where to go about this.

I was able to figure out that doing this would require a GPS file that has Data-Time elements.

```
clear;
clc;
% Specify folder where the files live 
myFolder = 'C:\Users\J87662\Desktop\GPX Data Files';
% Check to make sure folder exists. Warns user if doesn't. 
if ~isdir(myFolder)
    errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
    uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
    return;
end
% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
theFiles = dir(fullfile(myFolder, '*.gpx')); % Using .gpx as the desired file type.
% Number of files in the folder 
n = numel(theFiles);
data = cell(1,n);
% Figure with coastlines
figure
load coastlines
geoshow(coastlat, coastlon)
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [.56 .93 .56]);

% Plotting GPX Data
for k=1:n
    % Creates a colormap based on the amount of files we have
    cmap = hsv(k);
    % Read each file 
    data{k} = gpxread(fullfile( myFolder, theFiles(k).name )); 
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    geoshow(data{1,k}.Latitude, data{1,k}.Longitude);
    geoshow(data{1,k}.Latitude, data{1,k}.Longitude, 'Color', cmap(k,:),'LineWidth', 2);
    t = data{1,1}.Time;
    hold all
end
hold on
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code and comments below. Basically, the start time for a GPS file is stored in the first data point, and the end time is stored in the last data point. Combine all these start and end times in some array, and compare to your time selection criteria.

```
% init data types
data = cell(n, 1);
dataStartTimes = NaT(n, 1); % init with Not a Time (to store datetime objects)
dataEndTimes = NaT(n, 1);

% load data and get start and end times
for k = 1:n 
    data{k} = gpxread(fullfile( myFolder, theFiles(k).name));
    startTime = data{k}(1).Time; % first time registered
    endTime = data{k}(end).Time; % last time registered
    dataStartTimes(k) = regexprep(startTime, {'T', '.000Z'}, {' ', ''}); % convert to datetimes
    dataEndTimes(k) = regexprep(endTime, {'T', '.000Z'}, {' ', ''}); % convert to datetimes
end

% select gps files based on start and end time
startTime = datetime('21-08-2019 12:00:00', 'InputFormat', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'); % your selection criteria
endTime = datetime('22-08-2019 12:00:00', 'InputFormat', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');

selection_indices = find(dataStartTimes >= startTime & dataEndTimes <= endTime);

% select the data
data_selection = data(selection_indices);

% your plotting method:
for k=1:numel(data_selection)
    % Creates a colormap based on the amount of files we have
    cmap = hsv(numel(data_selection));

    geoshow(data{k,1}.Latitude, data{k,1}.Longitude);
    geoshow(data{k,1}.Latitude, data{k,1}.Longitude, 'Color', cmap(k,:),'LineWidth', 2);
end
```